# Ignore blank cells for an average in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm a little stuck with a sheet I'm creating at work.

Basically the sheet tracks performance across 3 fields for our suppliers: *Delivery*, *Product Quality* and *Supporting Documentation*.

I would like to do an average sum at the bottom of each of these fields, then an overall average.

However, the averages won't work unless every box has been populated, and as it's a continual assessment, this isn't possible. The average should not treat blank cells like zeros. How can I make it average only the cells that are populated and ignore the ones the aren't?

Comment: please add some sample data, without that it's difficult to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The *AVERAGE()* worksheet function should ignore blanks:

[image]

and if you wanted the average for *Acme*, in **E2** enter:

```
=AVERAGE(B2:D2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions to you question, one which becomes obvious is we rephrase your question:

1) From you want the average of the cells.
2) The average of answered cels.
3) The average of thew cells, ignore blank ones.

Now exel has a nice funtion called =ISBLANK.  You can combine this with an if statement so that you enter the value 0 when a cell is blank, and use the original value if it is not blank.

Example:
[image: Screenshot of excel]

The second solution is not to use the =ISBLANK() function but the =AVeRAGE() function.  Gary already answered that while I was makign screenshots. This might be the best since there is no need to reinvent the wheel. A good programmer (and lets consider excel a compiler) is lazy and uses good pre-built tools when they are available. And =AVERAGE is available.